# Negative angle in direction-magnitude vector form

Tags: vectors

If I want to convert component vector which is in IV quadrant into magnitude direction form.  Tan is negative in IV quadrant.  Why do we ignore the sign of the angle?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will necessarily answer your question.

The method to obtain the direction of a vector $\bf{a}$ is to use $\tan^{-1}(\frac{a_y}{a_x})$ where $a_i$ represents the corresponding component of the vector.

The way this method works is by constructing a small triangle connecting the head of the vector to the origin of the vector. Through elementary trigonometry we can find the angle of this triangle by using $\tan^{-1}(\frac{|a_y|}{|a_x|})$ as $|a_y|$ and $|a_x|$ make up the legs of the triangle. However, this does not tell us which quadrant the vector is located in, this is done by checking the sign of the coordinates. Sometimes to assist with this and make calculations faster the absolute values are dropped and you end up with $\tan^{-1}(\frac{a_y}{a_x})$. You can see from this formula that if $a_y$ and $a_x$ have the same sign (i.e. quadrant 1 or 3) it will be positive (likewise if $a_y$ and $a_x$ have different signs it (i.e. quadrant 2 or 4) it will be negative). Therefore, as far as the $\tan^{-1}$ is concerned quadrant 1 and 3 are indistinguishable (likewise for 2 and 4). The sign that you get on the angle is a result of the argument of $\tan$ being negative because you did not take the absolute value.